# How to overwrite the folder in s3 bucket when using sam deploy for lamda deployment

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am using the below command to deploy lambda. It always create a new folder(.template and 1 more) in s3 bucket when there is change in my lamda project files. I want to overwrite the folder, so at any point in time, I will be having only 1 folder. How to do that?

```
 sam deploy --no-fail-on-empty-changeset --s3-bucket bucketName --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --stack-name stackName --parameter-overrides "ParameterKey=Stage,ParameterValue=staging"
```

Comment: What's your motivation?  Prune non-current artifacts to save storage costs?

Comment: yes to save storage cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to keep deployment artefact buckets "tidy" is to add a [Bucket Lifecycle Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) that [expires](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-expire-general-considerations.html) (deletes) objects after an arbitrary number of days.

You can create the rule in the S3 Console (`Management > Lifecyle rules`). You can safely expire all the objects, including the "current" version. Artefacts are read only at deploy-time and will be re-created with the next `sam deploy`.